# Can class extend from anonymous class

Tags: java, inheritance, anonymous-class

I know normal usage of the anonymous and inner classes, but was interesting to know - if it is possible to create subclass for anonymous class. I've used search but nothing related was found.

I can't imagine how this syntax should be looks like, but is any possibility (may be using reflection) to create class which will extend from some anonymous class (may be override some methods) - or Anonymous classes are always final?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [JLS 15.9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5):

> An anonymous class is always implicitly final ([§8.1.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2)).

---

In the interest of "teach a person to fish:" I just went to the [index page for the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html), searched for "anonymous class" to find 15.9.5, clicked through, and the answer was right there at the start of the section.

Comment: Thank you, for answer it`s coming from JLS. But I'm also was interesting in possibility of ignoring this rule. If this able to do? I know that using reflection final modifier can be unset (but this is in normal case with fields). Can this be done for anonymous class and then created inheritor?

Comment: That seems like a different question, unless you want to know whether it can be done anonymous classes (as opposed to final classes in general). But there are quite a few answers on SO already pointing to the general question (basically, [no, you can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450667/) -- final is final).

Answer (score 1):

You can extend any class dynamically using a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) so essentially *yes - if the anonymous calss implements an interface*.

Comment: That's not extending the anonymous class, though, that's just creating another class that implements the given interface.

Comment: @yshavit - yes and no. You could create a Proxy that uses reflection to enhance the anonymous object so essentially extending an anonymous class - at a stretch. I'm merely pointing out that a Proxy is a powerful beast.